# How to solve JSONDecodeError while using WHILE loop

Tags: python, json, api, request

```
while url:
      post = session.post(login, data=payload)
      r = session.get(url)
      parsed = json.loads(r.text)
      # Retrieve json product data
      if parsed['links']['next'] is not 'null':
            url = 'https://testshop.example.com/admin/products' + str(parsed['links']['next'])
            time.sleep(2)
            for product in parsed['products']:
                parsed_result = product['id'] 
      else: 
           print('stop now!')
           break
```

SO I am using the code above to retrieve and print all the json data in my terminal. Everything is going fine until I retrieve the following error code at the end:

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Does anybody know what the cause is of this and how I can fix it?

This is my JSON format if that matters:

```
products: [
{
article_code: "123",
barcode: "456",
brand_id: 2600822,
created_at: "2018-05-31T15:15:34+02:00",
data01: "",
data02: "",
data03: "",
delivery_date_id: null,
has_custom_fields: false,
has_discounts: false,
has_matrix: false,
hits: 0,
hs_code: null,
id: 72660113,
image_id: null,
is_visible: false,
price_excl: 33.0165,
price_incl: 39.95,
price_old_excl: 0,
price_old_incl: 0,
product_set_id: null,
product_type_id: null,
search_context: "123 456 789",
shop_id: 252449,
sku: "789",
supplier_id: 555236,
updated_at: "2018-05-31T15:15:34+02:00",
variants_count: 1,
visibility: "hidden",
weight: 0,
nl: {
content: "",
fulltitle: "Grid Lifter",
slug: "grid-lifter",
title: "Grid Lifter"
}
],

links: {
first: ".json",
last: ".json?page=70",
prev: null,
next: ".json?page=2",
count: 3497,
limit: 50,
pages: 70
}
```

I am using this to paginate through all the pages.

Traceback:

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('loginlightspeedshop.py', wdir='C:/Users/Solaiman/.spyder-py3/SCRIPTS/Lightspeed scripts')

File "sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Solaiman/.spyder-py3/SCRIPTS/Lightspeed scripts/loginshop.py", line 33, in 
    parsed = json.loads(r.text)

File "C:\Users\Solaiman\Anaconda3\lib\json__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Comment: Can you provide the actual traceback? Best guess is that r.text is None or an empty string on the last iteration through the loop.

Comment: @MatthewStory I have added a traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting empty/not json response here:

```
r = session.get(url)
```

Try to print r.text before parsing it to detect problem cause. Or use try/except clause:

```
try:
    parsed = r.json()
except ValueError:
    print(r.text)
    break
```

Comment: Good one thanks for your answer, I see the error now. I get a 404 error, really weird. Maybe I sent too much requests to the page.